# How can I update phone call volume on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone

I've tried to use **MPVolumeView** to adjust the volume of phone call. But it's not work.
My test case is that take a phone call and use UISlider to control the volume. It's no used.
But when I press the hard-key, the volume is changed. So, I believe the volume of in-call is updated.

Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Apple's reply on July 26 2018, 9:03 AM.
"This is an unsupported request. "
I share this information for who has same problem.

[image]